# dygraphs fails on IE8 when options are used

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, dygraphs

The following HTML does not display a graph on IE8. Works fine on Firefox, Chrome, and IE9 and IE10. On IE8 all I can see are the captions (the dates) and "Barometric Pressure".
dygraph-combined.js is the current version. First six lines are as recommended. If you take the width option out, it works.

Just to make life more interesting, if I replaced width by ylabel:'millibars' it doesn't display the label. Gawds I hate IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE9">
<!--[if IE]><script src="/excanvas_r3/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="dygraph-combined.js"></script>
<title>Real-Time Hydrologic System</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="graphdiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  g = new Dygraph(

    // containing div
    document.getElementById("graphdiv"),

    // CSV or path to a CSV file.
    "http://ra-tes.org/bigrain-14.csv" , { width: 600 }
  );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which version of dygraphs are you using? Can you post a link using dygraphs.com/fiddle? Often this winds up being a trailing comma issue, but I don't see one in your code sample.

Comment: Latest -n- greatest. Try this: http://ra-tes.org/gsimpler.html although http://ra-tes.org/g.html is what I'm actually trying to make work. It's not obvious how to use jsfiddle. If it saves you a lot of time, I'll figure out how to use it, otherwise I have to beg off.

Comment: I'm getting an error at the first URL: "http://ra-tes.org/viz.cgi?siteid=15&variableid=236&from=&to=&graph=Barometric%20Pressure 500 (Internal Server Error) "

Comment: Sigh. Our database went down, and (HA!) our DBA (ME!) barely knows what he's doing. Thanks for trying ... I'll leave another comment here when the database has come back up. :(